# Validation Set has images from only one class if obtained through image_dataset_from_directory

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

I have the following function to return the training and validation dataset:

```py
def load_from_directory(path, shuffle=False):
  train_ds = tfk.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    directory=path,
    image_size=IMAGE_SIZE,
    validation_split=VALIDATION_SPLIT,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    seed=SEED,
    subset='training',
    label_mode='binary',
    shuffle=shuffle
  )

  val_ds = tfk.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    directory=path,
    image_size=IMAGE_SIZE,
    validation_split=VALIDATION_SPLIT,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    seed=SEED,
    subset='validation',
    label_mode='binary',
    shuffle=False
  )

  return train_ds, val_ds

train_ds, val_ds = load_from_directory(path=TRAINING_PATH, shuffle=True)
```

The problem is that after some strange results (validation precision 100% after 2nd epoch) I analyzed the composition of the validation set and came to the conclusion that it contain images from only one class.

This is very strange but I don't know how to handle it.
I am using the cats and dogs dataset from Microsoft which contains a ton of examples of each class.

To put in a chart the class distribution I am doing the following:

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go

labels = np.concatenate([y for _, y in train_ds], axis=0)
_, counts = np.unique(labels, return_counts=True)

fig = go.Figure(
  data=[
    go.Pie(
      labels=CLASS_NAMES, 
      values=counts, 
      hole=.5, 
      marker_colors=['rgb(205, 152, 36)', 'rgb(129, 180, 179)', 'rgb(177, 180, 34)']
    )], 
  layout_title_text='Train Class Frequency'
)

fig.update_layout(width=400, height=400)
fig.show()

labels = np.concatenate([y for _, y in val_ds], axis=0)
_, counts = np.unique(labels, return_counts=True)

fig = go.Figure(
  data=[
    go.Pie(
      labels=CLASS_NAMES, 
      values=counts, 
      hole=.5, 
      marker_colors=['rgb(205, 152, 36)', 'rgb(129, 180, 179)', 'rgb(177, 180, 34)']
    )], 
  layout_title_text='Validation Class Frequency'
)

fig.update_layout(width=400, height=400)
fig.show()
```

The even stranger thing is that with `suffle=True` for the creation of the dataset the dataset has the two classes in it, but it doesn't make sense to have that flag to True.

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8nEq.png)

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and do not see the problem. I used a data set with 2 classes.
and ran it with shuffle=True and also with shuffle=False. To test if val_ds has the right number of classes use

```
print(val_ds.class_names)
```

Comment: Replacing categorical for binary in the label_mode it will fix the problem. I think that was the problem in my case. Thanks for you help